# share /home with nfs automount

Tags: linux, nfs, automounting, home

server

```
vi /etc/exports
/home 10.10.10..0/24(rw,sync)
systemctl restart nfs-server
```

client

```
mkdir -p /home/user
showmount -e 10.10.10.1
vi /etc/auto.master
/-  /etc/auto.home
/home  /etc/auto.home
vi /etc/auto.home
*  -fstype=nfs,rw  10.10.10.1:/home
systemctl start autofs
 systemctl enable autofs
```

```
firewall disabled
```

now i have three users, only one of them can login with his home dir
the others two login with "/"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to add the ampersand at the end of the above line to **auto.home**  :

```
* -fstype=nfs,rw 10.10.10.1:/home/&
```

That's what will be the referring of each user home directory on the server side.

Remove the following entry : `/- /etc/auto.home`

Also you don't need to create `/home/user` directory ; because it will be available and mounted automatically for every user.

So this way users can access their shared NFS directories just by accessing `/home/<username>` on the client side.

Also make sure  on the client side that home directories does not exist.

But It's better to not  use wildcards so it won't mount all the remote home directories, instead you can put different entries in your `home.auto`:

```
<user1>    -fstype=nfs,rw 10.10.10.1:/home/<user1> 
<user2>    -fstype=nfs,rw 10.10.10.1:/home/<user2>
<user3>    -fstype=nfs,rw 10.10.10.1:/home/<user3>
```

Comment: thanks a lot for your comment , i changed as your advice used * as wildcard and now i have 3 users only one of them can login with his home dir but the other two users still login /

Comment: please put the content of every user home directroly by ls -ltr and also the mounts by : mount | grep autofs